# Check if one of the radio buttons has been selected or not

Tags: php

I want to check if one of the radio buttons has been selected or not, and if it is, then I want to print its value.

```
<form ....>
     Gender:<br />
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br />
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female<br />
</form>
```

I am trying this, but it gives error when none of the radio buttons is selected.

```
$selected_radio = $_POST['sex'];
if ($selected_radio == 'male') {
    print "Gender is male <br />";
}
else if ($selected_radio == 'female') {
    print "Gender is female <br />";
}
else {
    print "No gender selected. <br />";
}
```

Comment: you should type  `==` instead of `= =`.

Comment: Also `name="sex"` != `$_POST['gender']`

Comment: `isset($_POST['gender'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a **sintax** error in your comparison operation, equal sing should be `==` instead of `= =` please change

```
if ($selected_radio = = 'male') {
```

with

```
if ($selected_radio == 'male') {
```

and you should do the same for

```
else if ($selected_radio == 'female') {
```

Comparison operators documentation available [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

there is also an error in your form, your input should be `name="gender"` to match your code `$_POST['gender']`

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `= =` instead `==` and this was the problem

```
   $selected_radio = $_POST['gender'];
if ($selected_radio == 'male') {
    print "Gender is male"."<br/>";
}
else if ($selected_radio == 'female') {
    print "Gender is female"."<br/>";
}
else {
    print "No gender selected."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the gender information on your radio buttons' `value` attributes. No need to write them again in a string.
Your comparison operators must not be seperated by a space.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['sex']))  
        echo "Gender is " . $_POST['sex'];
    else 
        echo "No gender selected.";
?>
```

Or there is another single line solution:

```
<?php echo isset($_POST['sex']) ? "Gender is " . $_POST['sex'] : "No gender selected."; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

also the "= =" error

your input name is "sex"

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
```

and you are asking for "gender" :

```
$_POST['gender']
```

Answer (score 0):

If is not set, it is not checked.

```
if (isset($_POST['gender'])) {
    $selected_radio = $_POST['gender'];
    if ($selected_radio == 'male') {
        print "Gender is male"."<br/>";
    } else if ($selected_radio == 'female') {
        print "Gender is female"."<br/>";
    } else {
        print "form invalid submition. CSRF maybe";
    }
} else {
    print "no gender selected";
}
```